# Xamarin remove TableSection top border

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

Is it possible to remove the top blue border(or atleast change its color) of xamarins TableSection:

[image: http://imgur.com/btnlrMa]

I looked at Xamarin TableView documentation, but I found no help there:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
public class UserProfilePushNotification : TableView
    {
        public UserProfilePushNotification(string text) : base()
        {
            Intent = TableIntent.Data;
            Root = new TableRoot
            {
                new TableSection
                {
                    new SwitchCell
                    {
                        Text = text
                    },
                    new TextCell()
                    {
                        Text = string.Empty
                    },
                    new TextCell
                    {
                        Text = "Android Version: 1.2.1"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: @jzeferino don't worry I didn't forget you : ) I just didn't have the time to test it out before marking it as a correct answer, or asking something if it didn't work. I'll test it out after work.

Comment: Ok. let me know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was digging into this problem and I found that `TableView` is implemented (in the default renderer) as a `ListView`.
The `TableSection` is just a normal item in the `Listview`, the first one.

If you don't use the `Title` Property from the `TableSection` (in this case you aren't using it) you can hide it.

To do this I created a custom render for the `TableView` and hidden the first element of the `ListView`:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Project.MenuTableView), typeof(Project.Droid.MenuTableViewRenderer))]
namespace Project.Droid
{
    public class MenuTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
    {    
        private bool _firstElementAdded = false;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control == null)
                return;

            var listView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;    
            listView.ChildViewAdded += (sender, args) => 
            {    
                if (!_firstElementAdded)
                {    
                    args.Child.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;    
                    _firstElementAdded = true;    
                }

            };
            // Uncomment this if you want to remove all the dividers from the table.
            //listView.DividerHeight = 0;    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your idea works! But sadly it removes the top border, so it leaves me with a topless table view. Is there a way to leave the gray  border intact ? 

Or perhaps there is another way of me to achieve a data table with a swichcell ?

Comment: What top border it removes? It removes the blue bar. correct?

Comment: Yes because the first element is the table section and his has a blue divider. The only way I see is to try to color that divider. But it's another hacky